# How to get the output from docker run -i

Tags: dotcloud, docker

`docker run` normally returns the output of the command it runs. I need to pass some data to docker, run a command that processes the data, and return the output. When I use the `-i` option, no output is returned. Consider this simple example:

```
echo hello | docker run -i base wc
```

It returns no output. How can I get the output from docker when using the `-i` option?

Comment: Could you add the output of ``docker version``? I suspect this is a bug in whatever version you're running.

Comment: @Andy cant get output on 0.5.0

Answer (score 16):

The solution I came up with is:

```
ID=$(echo hello | docker run -i -a stdin base wc)
docker logs $ID
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way, but it works.

Comment: Great solution!